# problema com listar ítens desse objeto

Tags: php, api, rest

estou com um problema para pegar os dados recebidos da ordem de pagamento do `pagseguro`. estou fazendo a consulta ele esta me trazendo os resultados porem não consigo pegar o que tem dentro do `paymentOrders` pelo simples fato dele me trazer um código junto alguém saberia como faço para resolver isso?

abaixo o retorno

```
stdClass Object
(
    [date] => 2018-05-03T14:13:44-03:00
    [resultsInThisPage] => 2
    [currentPage] => 1
    [totalPages] => 1
    [paymentOrders] => stdClass Object
        (
            [98ECCE252FFE40FBAF8A143BF6B7C77A] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 98ECCE252FFE40FBAF8A143BF6B7C77A
                    [status] => 1
                    [amount] => 75
                    [grossAmount] => 0
                    [lastEventDate] => 2018-04-08T16:01:26-03:00
                    [schedulingDate] => 2018-05-08T06:01:24-03:00
                    [transactions] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [discount] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => DISCOUNT_PERCENT
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                )

            [CBA68FE94E0B49069397562DF8238AD9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => CBA68FE94E0B49069397562DF8238AD9
                    [status] => 2
                    [amount] => 75
                    [grossAmount] => 75
                    [lastEventDate] => 2018-04-08T16:01:26-03:00
                    [schedulingDate] => 2018-04-08T16:01:24-03:00
                    [transactions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [code] => BDEB784FE176479BA9844976DEC8B5D3
                                    [date] => 2018-04-08T16:01:24-03:00
                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [discount] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => DISCOUNT_PERCENT
                            [value] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa um `foreach()`

```
foreach($resultados->paymentOrders as $key => $value){
    var_dump($value);
    //ou abstrai as informações
    $code[$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: tentei utilizar como você descreveu foreach($resOrders->paymentOrders as $key => $value){
      var_dump($value);

  } porem me da o seguinte erro `Trying to get property of non-object` e tambem `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: apesar que pode ser porque o sandbox está em manutenção e voltará so as 19 se voce estiver testando em sandbox e claro.

Comment: vou verificar aqui, também uso o pagseguro, mas eu criei uma classe própria para as funcionalidades, logo aviso aqui.

Comment: e... estou testando em sandbox e acho que pode ser isso, pois voltei o codigo que estava antes e está com o mesmo erro

Comment: usei o codigo de exemplo que vc postou aqui, e o foreach funcionou corretamente. vou fazer um teste direto do sandbox, vc esta fazendo a busca por intervalo de datas?

Comment: nao estou utilizando mais precisamente essa url `https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pre-approvals/{preApprovalCode}/payment-orders?email=suporte%40lojamodelo.com.br&token=57BE455F4EC148E5A54D9BB91C5AC12C` e com o resultado dela eu quero pegar as ordens de pagamento certinhas uma por uma para serem mostradas

Comment: tenta esse `https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pre-approvals/payment-orders?email=suporte%40lojamodelo.com.br&token=57BE455F4EC148E5A54D9BB91C5AC12C` sem o `asdas/`

Comment: intao mas eu preciso do codigo dele para mostrar ao cliente que efetuou está assinatura se eu deixar sem vai mostrar todos de todos ai eu n quero eu quero que mostre tds as ordens do cliente em questao

Comment: o retorno da sua consulta é em xml?

Comment: nao e `json` o retorno